# Calculate grade in Python with letter

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to calculate the average and letter grade of a class. Every time I run the code it prints "Your Grade is an A". I think something is wrong with my def average() function, but I cannot figure it out.

It also only prints the Letter grade, and not the score also

```
homework1 = int(raw_input('Enter homework1 score: '))
homework2 = int(raw_input('Enter homework2 score: '))
quiz = int(raw_input('Enter quiz score: '))
exam = int(raw_input('Enter Final Exam Score: '))
if homework1 > 100:
        print 'Score cannot be greater than 100'
if homework1 < 0:
        print 'Score cannot be less than 0'
if homework2 > 100:
        print 'Score cannot be greater than 100'
if homework2 < 0:
        print 'Score cannot be less than 0'
if quiz > 100:
        print 'Score cannot be greater than 100'
if quiz < 0:
        print 'Score cannot be less than 0'        
if exam > 100:
        print 'Score cannot be greater than 100'
if exam < 0:
        print 'Score cannot be less than 0'   

numbers = [homework1, homework2, quiz, exam]               

def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    return total / len(numbers)

def get_average(numbers):
    homework = average("homework1, homework2")
    quiz = average("quiz")
    exam = average("exam")
    return .2*quiz + .2*exam + .6*homework    

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 93.333:
        return "Your grade is an A"
    elif score >= 90:
        return "Your grade is an A-"
    elif score >= 86.667:
        return "Your grade is a B+"
    elif (avg >= 83.333):
        return "Your grade is a B"
    elif (avg >= 80):
        return "Your grade is a B-"
    elif (avg >= 76.667):
        return "Your grade is a C+"
    elif (avg >= 73.333):
        return "Your grade is a C"
    elif (avg >= 70):
        return "Your grade is a C-"
    elif (avg >= 66.667):
        return "Your grade is an D"
    elif (avg >= 65):
        return "Your grade is an D-"
    else:
        return "Your grade is a F"
    if (avg == 0):
        return "There is an error"

print get_letter_grade(get_average)
```

Comment: You're passing a string to `average`.  Try passing it a list of numbers.

Comment: @TomKarzes While this is true, it looks like `average()` isn't called at all in the code, otherwise it would fail with exception instead of printing something.

Comment: Yeah you're right, there are way more problems than just that.  Why is a function being passed to `get_letter_grade`?

Comment: I initially did not have the code: `def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    return total / len(numbers)` But it was not working so I thought I needed to define average

Comment: First, your code is cut off in the question, with the most important parts of it missing. Second, your code is simply too large: try to split it into smaller pieces and test them separately, find the piece that behaves incorrectly and post **only** the incorrect piece instead of your entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting "Your grade is an A" everytime because you're calling `get_letter_grade` function with the function `get_average` as an input.

Since the evaluation `get_average > 93,333` is always `True`, then you won't get any other answer.

Give another go.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the code, I can see that you're passing **get_average()** (the function) to **get_letter_grade()** as a paremeter.

```
print get_letter_grade(get_average)
```

So that's the first thing. Also, what Tom Karzes already said about parsing strings to the **average()** when it clearly expects a list of numbers.

Comment: While I understand it's annoying not to be able to participate in comments, please refrain from posting answers that are not answers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reviewing your code. But to fix the problems in your code, this would do it:

```
homework1 = int(raw_input('Enter homework1 score: '))
homework2 = int(raw_input('Enter homework2 score: '))
quiz = int(raw_input('Enter quiz score: '))
exam = int(raw_input('Enter Final Exam Score: '))
if homework1 > 100:
        print 'Score cannot be greater than 100'
if homework1 < 0:
        print 'Score cannot be less than 0'
if homework2 > 100:
        print 'Score cannot be greater than 100'
if homework2 < 0:
        print 'Score cannot be less than 0'
if quiz > 100:
        print 'Score cannot be greater than 100'
if quiz < 0:
        print 'Score cannot be less than 0'        
if exam > 100:
        print 'Score cannot be greater than 100'
if exam < 0:
        print 'Score cannot be less than 0'   

numbers = [homework1, homework2, quiz, exam]               

def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    return total / len(numbers)

def get_average(numbers):
    # you accessed your array in the wrong way
    homework = average(numbers[0:1])
    quiz = average([numbers[2]])
    exam = average([numbers[3]])
    return .2*quiz + .2*exam + .6*homework    

def get_letter_grade(numbers):
    # here, you mixed up 'score' and 'avg' which were both not defined
    score = get_average(numbers)
    if score >= 93.333:
        return "Your grade is an A"
    elif score >= 90:
        return "Your grade is an A-"
    elif score >= 86.667:
        return "Your grade is a B+"
    elif (score >= 83.333):
        return "Your grade is a B"
    elif (score >= 80):
        return "Your grade is a B-"
    elif (score >= 76.667):
        return "Your grade is a C+"
    elif (score >= 73.333):
        return "Your grade is a C"
    elif (score >= 70):
        return "Your grade is a C-"
    elif (score >= 66.667):
        return "Your grade is an D"
    elif (score >= 65):
        return "Your grade is an D-"
    else:
        return "Your grade is a F"
    if (score == 0):
        return "There is an error"

# You used to call the get_letter_grade with a (not called) function as an argument
print get_letter_grade(numbers)
```

Comment: Explain what you changed to make the code works, otherwise your answer is useless.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Think I still need to review code to simplify, but am new to python